# Pre-commit-hooks without tag?

Tags: github, gitlab, pre-commit-hook, pre-commit.com

I have a GitLab repo, but no tags.
What is the initial tag of a repo? v1.0.0?

```
repos:
  - repo: https://gitlab.<company>.com/xxx/yyy/zzz.git
    rev: 1.0.0
    hooks:
      - id: black
      - id: trailing-whitespace
      - id: flake8
      - id: isort
```

Will it run?

Comment: either add a tag to the repository, or use a sha - the pre-commit creator

Answer (score 0):

According to [pre-commit docs](https://pre-commit.com/#pre-commit-configyaml---repos), you can specify revision sha of commit. e.g.

```yaml
rev: 84f01ac09fcd8610824f9626a590b83cfae9bcbd
```